# Editing Content in Experience Editor in Multi-site configuration

Tags: experience-editor, multisite

We have a multi-site setup and have the following `sites` defined in config:

```xml
<sites>
  <site name="mysite1" patch:before="*[@name='website']" rootPath="/sitecore/content/mysite1" startItem="home" hostName="mysite1.com" ... />
  <site name="mysite2" patch:after="*[@name='mysite1']" rootPath="/sitecore/content/mysite2" startItem="home" hostName="mysite2.com" ... />
</sites>
```

When content editors log in to the admin interface (*mysite1.com/sitecore*), they are able to see all the content in the tree for both sites, due to the way the roles and permissions are set up. Some users are in multiple roles and therefore can see content for multiple sites. The problem, however, is when a user tries to edit content using the Experience Editor—for `mysite2`, some elements of the site still refer to the logged-in site, e.g. `mysite1`.

Investigating further, it seems that `Sitecore.Context.Site` is set to `"mysite1"` in the Experience Editor.

What is the best way to allow the user to edit both sites separately in the Experience Editor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In multi-site solutions, when you edit an item in the Experience Editor, Sitecore will by default resolve the site context using the value of the setting `Preview.DefaultSite`. It's located in `Sitecore.config`, and my guess is that you currently have it set to `mysite1`:

```xml
<setting name="Preview.DefaultSite" value="mysite1"></setting>
```

This means the default site context used by the Experience Editor will be `mysite1`.

You can change this behavior by setting another setting called `Preview.ResolveSite` to `true`. That will make Sitecore correctly resolve the site context of the item being edited:

```xml
<setting name="Preview.ResolveSite" value="true"></setting>
```

Note that on some Sitecore revisions you will need to apply the following hotfix in order for this feature to work correctly:

**https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/382913**

Comment: Does the Preview.ResolveSite setting only append the sc_site querystring parameter or does the url change to the corresponding site path as well?

Answer (score 7):

The sites are recognized using `hostname` and `virtualPath`. If your users login to EE using hostname from `mysite1` and edit items they are using following url:

`http://mysite1?sc_itemid={...}`

so Sitecore, when attempting to recognize the site will match it to `mysite1` because the hostname will match even if the actual item is from `mysite2`

Comment: How should the content editors edit content for `mysite2` then?

Comment: They can access EE using http://mysite2/sitecore. Then sitecore will match second site. Or you can mess with site resolving logic on requestBegin