# Experience Editor edit mode doesn't work if "website" site node is not present

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

We are using a custom patch into Sitecore.config to define our own site node. It has pretty much the exact same settings as the default "website" site node except for the `name`, `hostname` and `rootpath`. It even has `enableWebEdit` set to `true`. When we remove the default website node, Experience Editor (specifically edit mode) no longer works. By that I mean, there are no editable regions for each field, and clicking on text does not give the user the feel they can change the text. It acts pretty much like preview mode.

We are just really curious why Sitecore needs the default website node for the XP editor to work? We are using `Glass().Editable()` in our views, in case it matters.

Comment: Did you configure a new default site for it?  https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/477/73

Comment: Can you post what version of Sitecore?

Comment: @MarkCassidy No, but upon discovering that setting and changing it to the `name` of our custom site node, we are able to remove or comment out the website node in Sitecore.config and the Experience Editor still works. I think this is the solution.

Comment: @PeteNavarra `Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161115`

Answer (score 2):

In versions of Sitecore 8.1 and above, the proper way to set the preview site DefaultSite is to set the configuration setting `Preview.DefaultSite` to something other than **website**.

```
<setting name="Preview.DefaultSite" value="mysite1"></setting>
```

> This might be a duplicate of question:
>
> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/477/246

Comment: This is great to know, but we are currently on `8.2 rev. 161115`, so I don't think it applies.

Comment: We were able to fix it be changing the `Preview.DefaultSite` property in `Sitecore.config` to the name of our custom site node.