# Experience editor always opens another site in a multi-site instance

Tags: experience-editor, settings

I have a multi-site instance having site1, site2, site3,...  and the instance name is Mysite.
Each site has its own `SiteDefinition.config`

When I try to open a site2 or site3 page in the experience editor, it opens the site1's home page.

On checking the `Mysite/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page, the site definition nodes are in this order - Site1, Site2, Site3. So, I modified site1 definition config to load after site2.

But now, when I browse site2 page in experience editor either by instance name (mysite/site2/home/somepage) or domain name (site2.com/somepage), it always loads the site2 home page.

Is there any setting for a multi-site instance to be able to see any site's page in experience editor irrespective of the site definition order.

using Sitecore 8.2

Comment: How are you trying to open the Experience editor? I think you are opening it via Sitecore Launchpag -> Experience Editor. Right? You can navigate to the item in the content editor and then open in Experience editor.

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay. I'm opening the item in the CE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting `Preview.ResolveSite` in `Sitecore.config`.

> If true, when a user previews an item, Sitecore tries to resolve the
>   root item and the context site based on the current content language
>               and the path to the item. If Sitecore cannot resolve the context site, it uses the site that is specified in the
>   Preview.DefaultSite setting.
>               Default value: true

```
<setting name="Preview.ResolveSite" value="true" />
```

In multi-site solutions, when opening an item in Experience Editor, it is important that `sc_site` query string parameter in the URL is set properly. The aforementioned setting helps with that. When the setting is set to `true`, it will resolve the context site based on the path to the item and the current content language. Then, the context site name will be appended to the `&sc_site` query string parameter properly.

http://yourhostname.com/?sc_mode=edit&sc_itemid=%7b3FC5EF65-8170-4EBB-BFBC-AD0CD0852521%7d&sc_version=1&sc_lang=en**&sc_site=current-context-site**

Please also refer to [this similar answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/477/5705).

Update:
In addition to this, you can check that these 3 settings are also set to true, the details are described in [this Sitecore Knowledge Base article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/986056):

> There are several settings that help to configure proper site
>   resolving logic in multisite Sitecore solutions:
>
> - Rendering.SiteResolving — enables site resolving, so cross-site links    can be rendered with correct hostname, language, and virtual
>     folder.
> - Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentSite — item location is taken into    consideration when a cross-site link is built. All items under
>     a    certain site root will be resolved in the context of that root.
> - Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentLanguage — when true, context    language is taken into consideration when a cross-site link is built.